# restrict focus on particular div

Tags: html

I have a popup div which has lot of controls. If i press on tab continiously the focus must not leave from the div to parent form.How to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to enforce in plain HTML.
There are however quite some scripts out there that take care of this for you. I would strongly suggest to use one of them as there are quite some problems that need to be addressed ([A dropdown might appear in front of your modal div](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2005/08/09/how-to-put-a-div-over-a-select-in-ie.aspx)).

If you are using asp.net you can check out the ajax control toolkit which has a modal popup dialog.

Nearly every decent javascript framework has plugins to accomplish this aswell. I happen to work a lot with jQuery which has a number of plugins to handle this:

- jQuery Block UI (http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#dialog)
- jQuery Popup Dialog (http://vision-media.ca/resources/jquery/jquery-popup-plugin-review)
- jQuery modal dialog boxes (http://www.84bytes.com/2008/06/02/jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/)
- ... there are a lot more to be found at http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/popup

And if you find the need to make one yourself, here is a tutorial on how to do it using jQuery: http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial

Good luck with finding a solution that fits you best!

Answer (score 0):

In the **onblur** event of the last control move the focus to the first control inside the div.

Answer (score 0):

try using a [modal div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206113/are-modal-dialogs-a-good-practice-for-the-web) if you want to absolutely ensure that the focus doesn't leave.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented mini-framework based on gather knowledge including answers in this post.

It uses JQuery UI.

Improvements are welcome.

Here is framework object:

```
var TabLim = {};

TabLim.activate = function(el) {
    TabLim.deactivate();

    TabLim._el = el;

    $(window).on('keydown', TabLim._handleTab);

    return TabLim;
};

TabLim.deactivate = function() {
    TabLim._el = null;

    // detach old focus events
    TabLim._detachFocusHandlers();

    TabLim._els = null;
    TabLim._currEl = null;

    $(window).off('keydown', TabLim._handleTab);

    return TabLim;
};

TabLim.setFocus = function(prev) {
    // detach old focus events
    TabLim._detachFocusHandlers();

    // scan for new tabbable elements
    var tabbables = TabLim._el.find(':tabbable');
    TabLim._els = [];

    // wrap elements in jquery
    for ( var i = 0; i < tabbables.length; i++) {
        var el = $(tabbables[i]);
        // set focus listener on each element
        el.on('focusin', TabLim._focusHandler);
        TabLim._els.push(el);
    }

    // determine the index of focused element so we will know who is
    // next/previous to be focused
    var currIdx = 0;
    for ( var i = 0; i < TabLim._els.length; i++) {
        var el = TabLim._els[i];

        // if focus is set already on some element
        if (TabLim._currEl) {
            if (TabLim._currEl === el[0]) {
                currIdx = i;

                prev ? currIdx-- : currIdx++;
                break;
            }

        } else {
            // focus is not set yet.
            // let's set it by attribute "autofocus".
            if (el.attr('autofocus') !== undefined) {
                currIdx = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (currIdx < 0) {
        currIdx += TabLim._els.length;
    }
    if (TabLim._els.length) {
        TabLim._els[Math.abs(currIdx % TabLim._els.length)].focus();
    }

    return TabLim;
};

TabLim._handleTab = function(e) {
    if (e.which === 9) {
        e.preventDefault();

        TabLim.setFocus(e.shiftKey);
    }
};

TabLim._focusHandler = function(e) {
    TabLim._currEl = e.currentTarget;
};

TabLim._detachFocusHandlers = function() {
    if (TabLim._els) {
        for ( var i = 0; i < TabLim._els.length; i++) {
            TabLim._els[i].off('focusin', TabLim._focusHandler);
        }
    }
};
```

How to use it:

1) to activate to limit focus on specific div

```
TabLim.activate($('.yourDic')).setFocus();
```

2) to deactivate

```
TabLim.deactivate();
```